# How do I use the variable out of its asynchronous function scope

Tags: javascript, variables, asynchronous, scope

I need to use the variable that I declared inside the asynchronous function out of that scope. Is that possible?

```
movies.forEach((movie) => {
    const { title, poster_path, vote_average, overview, release_date, id } = movie

    async function getCredits(url) {
        const res = await fetch(url)
        const data = await res.json()

        const directors = [];
        
        const directorsName = directors.join(", ") // The one I want to bring out of its scope
    }

    const CREDITS_URL = `the credits url goes here and it uses this -> ${id}`
    getCredits(CREDITS_URL)

    const directorsName = directors.join(", ") // Like this

    const card = document.createElement("div")
    card.innerHTML = `
        <div class="director">
                <h3>Directed by ${directorsName}</h3> // This is where I need the variable
        </div>
    `
    cards.appendChild(card)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to return something from your `async` function. You can move your `getCredits` function out of the loop, and make the loop `async`, something like:

```
async function getCredits(url) {
  const res = await fetch(url)
  const data = await res.json()
  const directors = [];
  // Do something with data?
  
  return directors.join(", ");
}

movies.forEach(async (movie) => {
  const { id } = movie

  const CREDITS_URL = `the movie url goes here and it uses this -> ${id}`
  const response = await getCredits(CREDITS_URL);

  const card = document.createElement("div")
  card.innerHTML = `
      <div class="director">
              <h3>Directed by ${response}</h3> // This is where I need the variable
      </div>
  `
  cards.appendChild(card)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to have the DOM be created more quickly and have a sort of "lazy loading" of directors' names, you could do something like this:

```
movies.forEach((movie) => {
  const { title, poster_path, vote_average, overview, release_date, id } = movie;

  const card = document.createElement('div');
  card.innerHTML = `<div class="director">
          <h3>Directed by <span class='dname'>...</span></h3>
        </div>`;
  const dname = card.querySelector('.dname');

  async function getCredits(url) {
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const data = await res.json();

    const directors = [];

    dname.textContent = directors.join(', ');
  }

  const CREDITS_URL = `the credits url goes here and it uses this -> ${id}`;
  getCredits(CREDITS_URL);

  cards.appendChild(card);
});
```

Here you're creating the div and appending it immediately, but with a `...` for directors' names. But you put that part in a span and then set the textContent of the span once `getCredits` resolves.

*Edit: This also has the added side-benefit of preventing HTML injection from your director's return, by not inserting them using `innerHTML`.